# How to Style UI use Antd for upload image

Tags: css, file-upload, antd

I want ui by antd[image]

I try display: 'grid', gridTemplateColumns: 'auto auto auto' but I have[image]

Comment: please refer [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)